# Headings had had their hints long long time ago

Tags: riddle, word

```
Hello everybody, can someone help me? This riddle really gave me the gilles so far. 
I need to solve this for school but I have no idea! joking ;) 
Not sure if it will help - check this out. So funny!
```

You're very close
But I'm always ahead
Can be beheaded
but can't be fed

You can have
a look inside
there will be
no place to hide

However,
You try to enter me
and more room arises
suddenly

Can you explain this trick to me?

> This is so easy!

Comment: Seems like a book. But some lines don't make sense.

Comment: Sounds like the "future"

Comment: +1 for "gave me the gilles" :-p Could it be the Tardis? (Multiple dose of cyanide coming up from me soon!)

Comment: I looked up "Tardis". No, to all of you:)

Comment: [There is another Gilles](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/97/gilles). This is going to be confusing!

Comment: @randal'thor that's Gilles-Putin, then there's OGilles (the OG)

Comment: So does the link to 'had ... had' suggest something should be read with non-obvious spacing/punctuation? I'm particularly looking at "can be beheaded" since it has two doubles.

Comment: @randal'thor maybe it's "can be"?

Comment: I like the Buffalo sentence more.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo

Comment: @avigrail And that one can even be extended with two more "Buffalo"s and still maintain correct punctuation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simply:

> Hat

You're very close
But I'm always ahead

> Ahead -> A-head -> A-het -> A-hat (just keep saying it over and over again (see title))

Can be beheaded

> You can take me off your head :D

but can't be fed

> Indicates inanimate - but since "can be beheaded" seems a contradiction - thus is the art of riddles.

You can have
a look inside
there will be
no place to hide

> This inanimate object is hollow but not large enough to hide inside.

However,
You try to enter me

> "U" try to enter. "U" displaces "A".

and more room arises
suddenly

> Hat -> Hut. A hut is larger than a hat. By putting a "U" in the hat (displacing "A") more room has been created :)

Comment: Congratulations. You found out about the trick. Now you can do a magic show :)

Comment: Good one 'cop! :-) @avigrail - that third verse was *really* evil :-[ :-)

Comment: @randal'thor I already told cop that I didn't expect it to be this hard :/

Answer (score 3):

I know this isn't the right answer, but **this question** posted on Puzzling Stack Exchange almost applies...

1. "You're very close but I'm always ahead"

This could mean our answers are close to correct, that we are physically located close to the right answer (right on our screens), or could be a reference to the fact that the question will always be located just ahead (above) the correct answer on our screens.

2. "Can be beheaded"

We can edit the heading

3. "You can have a look inside, there will be no place to hide"

We can attempt to edit your question, where you will not be able to conceal any additional hints from us that are hidden when viewed normally. Also there is no place to fit additional text when editing the question...

4. "However, try to enter me, more room arises suddenly"
   until we hit "enter" on the keyboard and more room arises for us to type in.

Just thought that was interesting...
Since you said you need this for school, it sadly can't be the correct answer. :(

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing! I dont need this for school actually. I was just hinting to the latest rumors and annoying some people. I wanted this puzzle to fit the Q&A-Style :D

Comment: "We can attempt to edit your question, where you will not be able to conceal any additional hints from us that are hidden when viewed normally" - that's exactly what he did with his last riddle! Nice idea though.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be a

> conjuror's hat?

*You're very close 

But I'm always ahead*

> When wearing a hat, you are very close to it, but it's always above ('ahead of'?) your head (so the word 'ahead' is sort of wordplay too).

*Can be beheaded 

but can't be fed*

> 'Beheaded' is here used to mean 'removed from the head'. (The OP is not a native English speaker!) And certainly a hat can't be fed.

*You can have 

a look inside 

there will be 

no place to hide 

However, 

try to enter me 

more room arises 

suddenly*

These verses are what makes it a

> *conjuror's* hat

rather than just a

> hat.

You can look inside this object, and indeed there appears to be no place to hide. But

> when the conjuror is performing 'magic' with it on stage, he can produce all sorts of objects, most famously rabbits, from the apparently empty hat, and also make them disappear into it. So for a rabbit, trying to enter the hat may lead to 'more room arising suddenly'.

Credit to @d'alar'cop for the idea of a

> hat,

but he couldn't make this fit with the 3rd verse. The only remaining mystery is the relevance of the multi-'had' sentence linked to by the OP - maybe it's a red herring, or just a hint to a word which sounds like 'had'?

Comment: There is a lot of correct stuff. But the third verse remains unsolved :) I dont even know what a conjuror is.

Comment: @avigrail - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_(illusion)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be a

> Shadow

I guess explanation won't be required after you revisit your's:-)

You're very close
But I'm always ahead
Can be beheaded
but can't be fed

> A shadow is always very close to you and ahead of you. Sometimes, because of the light's angle or broad daylight, you can behead it ( remove the head or kill its existence).

You can have
a look inside
there will be
no place to hide

> Wherever you go, it follows.

However,
You try to enter me
and more room arises
suddenly

> Since the shodow moves with you, when you try to catch it ( as we must have tried as a child :) ), it moves with us and sometimes growing bigger.

Answer (score 1):

> A pair of eye glasses

For obvious reasons; the first two verses, respectively: location of application and translucency. Taking poetic license for the third verse, that while in use, they have been 'entered' and provide more 'room' that you can:

> -*see*. "It's just a trick of the light."

Comment: Good guess but no :)